# How to hide map but show other layers

Tags: google-maps-android-api-2

I am developing a simple map app using Google Maps API v2 for Android.

The data that is displayed are:

a. The map layer (the satellite view from Google Maps);

b. The political map layer (KML);

c. Some custom markers from user (KML).

I would like to add a button to toggle show/hide each layer. I can do it for layers "b" and "c" (e.g. [Hiding/showing a kml layer on customized google maps depending of the view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22085308/hiding-showing-a-kml-layer-on-customized-google-maps-depending-of-the-view)), but how to do it with layer "a"???

I searched a lot and did not find how to do it using only that API. Is it possible?

Comment: Isn't the mapType MAP_TYPE_NONE exactly what you are looking for?

Comment: Works! Answer that question and I'll assign it as THE answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mapType MAP_TYPE_NONE positions the custom tiles according to the camera position, but does not show its own map tiles.