# how to hide or show KML layer in google map Android studio

Tags: android

my code is here to upload the kml file .

```
    layer = new KmlLayer(mMap, inputstrm, getApplicationContext());
                                    layer.addLayerToMap();
    layer.visibility(true);
```

I have loaded KML file in googleMap android studio but I can not figure out how to make layer visible status.there is my problem Please someone help

Comment: Though [it's javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22086770/1986241), I believe both are the same. Try `layer.setMap(null)` and `layer.setMap(mMap)`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If your layer can call visibility，try this:

```
layer.visibility(View.GONE);
```

or

```
layer.visibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

accoriding to your test , change to this, try it:

```
layer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);//show

layer.setVisibility(View.GONE);//hide  ， or use View.INVISIBLE
```

Comment: Thank you sir. but I cant call  visibility from the layer objects.

Comment: KmlLayer does no have these methods.